# Is there any way to store a multidimensional array in coreData?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, core-data

How can i store multidimensional array e.g [String],[[String]] in core Data using swift. If anybody know plese explain briefly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use dictionary of type `[String: [String]]`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Core Data "transformable" attribute. If the array only contains `String`, then Core Data will automatically convert it to/from binary data as needed. However you can't use transformable attributes as part of predicates, which means you can't search for entries where the array contains a specific string. If that doesn't matter to you then transformable is probably what you need. If that does matter, you probably need to reconsider your data model somewhat, possibly converting your two-dimensional array to attributes of new Core Data entities.